# FB Like Box not showing stream

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-likebox

I don't think it is an issue with the code I am using, but cannot get my FB Like Box to show the stream.

For example, I can go to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ and place in one Facebook page and it shows the stream fine. Yet, when I put in https://www.facebook.com/HHSE.hannoverhouse/ it doesn't work.

So, it must have to do with the type of page or some setting, but I've been over everything I can imagine such as Manage Permissions and such to make sure the page is viewable by all.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure that you have posted something within the last month.**

I had the exact same issue with my page where my stream wasn't showing up but some pages were showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML5, XFBML, IFRAME, URL coding is irrelevant.... it could be due to Facebook changing it's policies again!

I have the same problem with my facebook page link:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Brunito-Salsa-Salsa-Federation/185732888166103

But my friends page works just fine the page link is:

https://www.facebook.com/rubixsound

They both where tested using the facebook like box plugin page directly even before completing the plugin process, on the facebook page URL section..

..you paste the facebook page URL & you get an empty feed example, but with the other URL you get a full feed.

Answer (score 0):

The like box was made to be used on Canvas applications and web apps outside of Facebook. You don't need a Like box on a Facebook page as there is already a like button and the purpose of this page is to display a stream.

**Update**: Now I understand your issue. Which version are you using (HTML5, XFBML, IFRAME, URL)? Did you replace the appId parameter by HHSE.hannoverhouse's Id? Do you have any error showing in Firebug ("*it doesn't work*" is not precise enough)? Could you also include (if possible) a public URL where I could see the error?

Comment: That is what we're trying to implement, a like box on a website outside of Facebook, that has the stream to our Facebook page. Our thoughts are it is an issue with the Facebook page itself, which is why I included its URL. We can put in another Facebook page of ours and see its stream, but not this one and a few others.